# Huge pdo_mysql.log - turning off logging doesn't stop it from growing

Tags: mysql, magento-1.6, mysql-config

Magento is logging SQL queries even after I turned logging off in /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php. Wondering if there's something I'm missing?

These are the spots that are set to false:

```
    protected $_debug               = false;

/**
 * Minimum query duration time to be logged
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $_logQueryTime        = 2.5;

/**
 * Log all queries (ignored minimum query duration time)
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_logAllQueries       = false;

/**
 * Add to log call stack data (backtrace)
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_logCallStack        = false;

/**
 * Path to SQL debug data log
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
```

I need to regularly delete var/debug/pdo_mysql.log or it will grow to several gigs in size.

Debug mode is disabled in the admin area (System - Configuration - Developer - Debug set to no).

Looking for some advice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if this is the only file was modified, then i guess opcode cache?

Comment: I've inherited a site with this exact issue - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This logging should be off by default in a clean install of magento so it sounds like someone has previously modified this file to turn this setting on.

That said, now that logging is disabled I see no reason why the PDO adapter should be logging queries. As suggested above if you are using APC or opcache try clearing that as because this is a change to a php file rather than a db setting it may be cached at the php level.

Comment: Yes, `$_debug = false` turns off all logging to `pdo_mysql.log`. So it's either APC or the class has been overridden in `app/code/{core|local|community}/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

Comment: @fschmengler - I've checked both of these ideas but the log is still being generated. Do you have any other idea where the debug option could be getting overridden? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Debug mode might be on. Go to System - Configuration - Developer - Debug and if the Profiler is set to Yes, disable it.