# What steps/tasks are invloved in displaying the products list page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, product-list

I am a complete newbie in magento. My site uses magento 1.

There are n number pf tasks that happen when we display products on products list page or when we filter the products(on the frontend part). I am required to find out the time each of those tasks requires to complete.

I have been searching for a whole day what tasks are involved in displaying products on products list page but to no avail.

So my question is what all tasks are happening while displaying the products list page and where can I find it in the code for magento.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the flow of an action, use the below line of the code at the end of the point where you want to back trace.

In your case, add the below line of the code at the end of the product listing phtml file.

```
Mage::log(debug_backtrace()[1][function],null,'backtrace_debug.log');
```

This will log all the information you need regarding the flow in the var/log/backtrace_debug.log file. This will give you a lead on how to further track execution time.

Comment: I found this link :-
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/23915/67749

this works too

Comment: Great. If my solution helped, either accept or upvote it. Otherwise, we can also mark this as a duplicate of the other post you mentioned.

Comment: sorry, I do not have enough reputation to upvote it.

Comment: Never mind. Glad that you have got that your solution.